# How to get google traffic status in android application?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api-console

I want to get the traffic status which is recently introduced in Google MAP in my application.
Is it possible to do this with Google MAP V2? 
And I don't want to simply launch already installed google MAP app.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "get the traffic status".

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 GoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true)
```

also see this

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap